# Unattended Windows server 2012R2 with WSUS updates and Local Group Policies

Tags: windows-server-2012, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2, unattended

I am working on a project on automating windows (2012 STD, R2 and 2008R2) Image creation for which I am creating the Autouattend file for 2012 R2 using WSIM. I have created almost everything except configuring the WSUS updates and local Group Policies. I have written script for setting up automatic windows update and set WSUS intranet IP and call the same during OOBE phase. I have hardcoded the IP address in answer file which will connect to our WSUS server(after opening necessary ports) and need to remove it before calling sysprep in answer file(oobe phase)

I was also wondering if there is a way to set the local Policies (Security Setting) using the answer file.

Comment: Why don't you let Group Policy take care of these things? I'm assuming these machines are being joined to an AD domain?

Comment: Not all the instance spawn using the image will be in AD.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked into this before, but I've never come across a native setting in the answer file for local group policy options.

That being said, Group Policy settings are just registry entries, which you absolutely CAN set via answer file.

You can examine the local templates in the `%SystemRoot%\PolicyDefinitions` folder with a text editor to determine which keys are modified on the policies you wish to use.